# Fixing my class name & one method in Java

Tags: java, class, methods

I know these must be basic errors, but I'm not sure how to fix them.

I changed my class name to Interface & now Java has a problem with it.

Also, in my switch statement, I've tried to call the enterData method, but I'm getting an error on this line as well as on this line... "private static void enterData()" <-- it says a "token" is missing on this line?

I'm trying to call a method from case 0, but it isn't working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Interface { 
        private void run() 
        {

            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            Store store1 = new Store(); // MUST DO THIS

            int demandRate, option, end;
            double setupCost, unitCost, inventoryCost;
            double sellingPrice, optimalOrder;
            String name;

            do {
                System.out.println("Enter product data (0), Show product data (1), Show product strategy (2), Exit program (9).");
                option = console.nextInt();
                switch(option)
                {
                case 0: enterData();
                        break;
                case 1:
                        break;
                case 2:
                        break;
                case 9: System.out.println("You chose to exit the program.");
                        break;
                default: System.out.println("Please choose a valid option.");
                }
            } while (option != 9);

            private static void enterData()
            {
                System.out.println("Product name between 3 & 10 characters long: ");
                name = console.nextLine();
                while ((name.length() < 3) || (name.length() > 10)) {
                    System.out.println("Please put in a name between 3 & 10 characters long.");
                    name = console.nextLine();
                }           
                name = name.toLowerCase();

                System.out.println("Demand rate: ");
                demandRate = console.nextInt();
                while (demandRate <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Please put in a positive integer.");
                    demandRate = console.nextInt();
                }

                System.out.println("Setup cost: ");
                setupCost = console.nextDouble();
                while (setupCost <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Please put in a positive number.");
                    setupCost = console.nextInt();
                }

                System.out.println("Unit cost: ");
                unitCost = console.nextDouble();
                while (unitCost <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Please put in a positive number.");
                    unitCost = console.nextInt();
                }

                System.out.println("Inventory cost: ");
                inventoryCost = console.nextDouble();
                while (inventoryCost <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Please put in a positive number.");
                    inventoryCost = console.nextInt();
                }

                System.out.println("Selling price: ");
                sellingPrice = console.nextDouble();
                while (sellingPrice <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Please put in a positive integer.");
                    sellingPrice = console.nextInt();
                }
               }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
     Interface intFace = new Interface(); 
     intFace.run(); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: You cannot have methods inside methods.

Comment: also the name "interface" is reserved in java just like int, double, extends etc. For a full list of all reserved words see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: `interface` is reserved. `Interface` is not (though it is arguably a confusing choice of name and should be avoided)

Comment: And the bracket terminating the run() method after the do-while is missing.

Comment: @dehlen.. the keyword interface is case sensitive. We could create class with name Interface.. with uppercase 'I'

Comment: Okay, I've changed the name of the class. How could I get separate methods to run using this switch statement?

Comment: My IDE wouldn't allow "Interface"? I changed it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define method in another method.
Change your code to this:

```
public class Interface {
    private void run() 
    {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Store store1 = new Store(); // MUST DO THIS

        int demandRate, option, end;
        double setupCost, unitCost, inventoryCost;
        double sellingPrice, optimalOrder;
        String name;

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter product data (0), Show product data (1), Show product strategy (2), Exit program (9).");
            option = console.nextInt();
            switch(option)
            {
            case 0: enterData();
                    break;
            case 1:
                    break;
            case 2:
                    break;
            case 9: System.out.println("You chose to exit the program.");
                    break;
            default: System.out.println("Please choose a valid option.");
            }
        } while (option != 9);
    }
    private static void enterData()
    {
        int demandRate, option, end;
        double setupCost, unitCost, inventoryCost;
        double sellingPrice, optimalOrder;
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Product name between 3 & 10 characters long: ");
        String name = console.nextLine();
        while ((name.length() < 3) || (name.length() > 10)) {
            System.out.println("Please put in a name between 3 & 10 characters long.");
            name = console.nextLine();
        }           
        name = name.toLowerCase();

        System.out.println("Demand rate: ");
        demandRate = console.nextInt();
        while (demandRate <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please put in a positive integer.");
            demandRate = console.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Setup cost: ");
        setupCost = console.nextDouble();
        while (setupCost <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please put in a positive number.");
            setupCost = console.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Unit cost: ");
        unitCost = console.nextDouble();
        while (unitCost <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please put in a positive number.");
            unitCost = console.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Inventory cost: ");
        inventoryCost = console.nextDouble();
        while (inventoryCost <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please put in a positive number.");
            inventoryCost = console.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Selling price: ");
        sellingPrice = console.nextDouble();
        while (sellingPrice <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please put in a positive integer.");
            sellingPrice = console.nextInt();
        }
       }


    public static void main(String[] args) { 
     Interface intFace = new Interface(); 
     intFace.run(); 
     } 

}
```

Comment: Mark answer as correct if it fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a separate method and make those fields global. Something like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Interface {

    int demandRate, option, end;
    double setupCost, unitCost, inventoryCost;
    double sellingPrice, optimalOrder;
    String name;

    private void run() {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Store store1 = new Store(); // MUST DO THIS
        do {
            System.out
                    .println("Enter product data (0), Show product data (1), Show product strategy (2), Exit program (9).");
            option = console.nextInt();
            switch (option) {
            case 0:
                enterData(console);
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println("You chose to exit the program.");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please choose a valid option.");
            }
        } while (option != 9);
    }

    private void enterData(Scanner console) {
        System.out.println("Product name between 3 & 10 characters long: ");
        name = console.nextLine();
        while ((name.length() < 3) || (name.length() > 10)) {
            System.out
                    .println("Please put in a name between 3 & 10 characters long.");
            name = console.nextLine();
        }
        name = name.toLowerCase();

        System.out.println("Demand rate: ");
        demandRate = console.nextInt();
        while (demandRate <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please put in a positive integer.");
            demandRate = console.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Setup cost: ");
        setupCost = console.nextDouble();
        while (setupCost <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please put in a positive number.");
            setupCost = console.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Unit cost: ");
        unitCost = console.nextDouble();
        while (unitCost <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please put in a positive number.");
            unitCost = console.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Inventory cost: ");
        inventoryCost = console.nextDouble();
        while (inventoryCost <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please put in a positive number.");
            inventoryCost = console.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Selling price: ");
        sellingPrice = console.nextDouble();
        while (sellingPrice <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please put in a positive integer.");
            sellingPrice = console.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interface intFace = new Interface();
        intFace.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Interface is some kind of an abstract class definition keyword in java.
You can use a keyword to name your class with capitalized letters, but seriously, don't do this.

And you are not calling a method, you are implementing it in another method. You should go over writing and calling a method in java once again ;)

Comment: OP uses capitalized `Interface`, not `interface`. That is perfectly valid, albeit debatable naming.

Comment: I don't see what the debate is about, it's a directly poor name to use as its the exact same letters as the interface keyword is. Capitalized or not you should NEVER do this.